# Show that $X_n$ converge a.s

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales, almost-everywhere

I want to solve the following exercise from Durrett:

"Let $X_n, n\geq0$ be a submartingale with $\sup X_n<\infty$. Let $\xi_n = X_n - X_{n-1}$ and suppose $\mathbb{E}\left(\sup\xi^+\right)<\infty$.  Show that $X_n$ converge a.s. "

I am not sure to understand the hypothesis on the increments because I have the feeling that I can solve the exercise without it :
$\sup X_n<\infty$ implies that we can find $K$ such that for all integer n $X_n<K$ thus we can consider the submartingale $Y_n = X_n - K$ and since $\sup\mathbb{E}(Y_n^+)=0 < \infty$ by the Martingale convergence theorem $Y_n$ converge a.s and thus $X_n$ too.

Is this correct ?

Comment: I think the condition $\sup_n X_n < \infty$ is to be understood in a pointwise sense, i.e. $\sup_n X_n(\omega)<\infty$ for each **fixed** $\omega \in \Omega$. In general, it is then not possible to find a (deterministic) constant $K$ such that $\sup_n X_n(\omega) \leq K$ for **all** $\omega \in \Omega$.

Comment: Ok, so I have to show that $\sup \mathbb{E}(X_n^+) < \infty$ to apply the martingale convergence theorem, but I don't know where to start